# Gpu is shown twice, once as HIP device with invalid attributes, how can I fix this error in hashcat?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, arch-linux, gpu

Can I somehow unistall/disable the HIP device/
driver? I'm using Arch Linux.

`Hashcat -I` is giving the following information:

```
HIP Info:

=========

HIP.Version.: 5.1.20531

Backend Device ID #1
  Name...........: AMD Radeon RX 590 Series
  Processor(s)...: 0
  Clock..........: 0
  Memory.Total...: 0 MB
  Memory.Free....: 0 MB
  PCI.Addr.BDFe..: 0000:00:00.0
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" in the title. You will be able to accept your answer after a day or two using the "tick" mark next to it. [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed in the newest (not officially released version) of hashcat.